# iOS WidgetKit - Widget Preview Screen Not Updating on updating the Placeholder View

Tags: ios, ios14, widgetkit

I am using `XCode 12 beta 2` on `iOS 14 Simulator` & am trying to update the Widget Preview Screen (i.e. the screen which appears when we try to add a new widget) from the Placeholder View

```
struct PlaceholderView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Preview Title")
    }
}
```

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've already sorted this out, but since then placeholders are set from these functions:

```
// Placeholder
func placeholder(in context: Self.Context) -> Self.Entry 

// Widget Galery
func getSnapshot(in context: Self.Context, completion: @escaping (Self.Entry) -> ())
```